# Spring Security - LDAP - BadCredentialsException:

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am not able to validate a user using spring security, I get a BadCredentailException. 
My spring security configuration is:

```
<bean id="contextSource"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://ldaps.prod.sam.com:636"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=!testUser1,OU=Service Accounts,OU=User Accounts,DC=prod,DC=sam,DC=com"/>
    <property name="password" value="!!testPass1!!"/>
    <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch" id="ldapSearchBean">
    <constructor-arg value="OU=User Accounts,DC=prod,DC=sam,DC=com"/>
    <constructor-arg value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator" id="ldapBindAuthenticator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapSearchBean"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <constructor-arg value="ou=Groups"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="memberOf"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper" id="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper">
</bean>
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapBindAuthenticator"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="false"/>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="ldapUserDetailsContextMapper" />
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:178)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:61)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
```

When I step through the validation of the ldap user is successful it's the test user validation that fails. I think the issue is with the base path. Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Test your configuration by using the `ldapsearch` command line utility to attempt to authenticate a connection to your directory server.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)

Comment: The issue is with the search bean. If i use the same user and password to bind to ldap in the contextSource bean it works. Need to figure out how o adjust the base path in the search bean.